# Delete the last character in a specific column in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a **|** delimited file in the below format

```
U|0|1|10.95|10.95|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790_|1| | |Y|N/A|   
V|0|1|12.65|12.65|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790#|1| | |Y|N/A|   
P|0|1|15.57|15.57|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790!|1| | |Y|N/A|
```

I need to delete the last character in the 20th column of all the records.
"_, #, !" in this case.

Expected output:

```
U|0|1|10.95|10.95|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|   
V|0|1|12.65|12.65|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|   
P|0|1|15.57|15.57|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|
```

How can I do that using sed or awk or any unix command. Please note this is not a fixed length file, size of records may vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }{ sub(/.$/, "", $20) }1' file
```

- `.$` - where `.` is any character at the end of the string `$`

The output:

```
U|0|1|10.95|10.95|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|
V|0|1|12.65|12.65|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|
P|0|1|15.57|15.57|0|0|0|0| |0| |0| |N|N| |N| |10335790|1| | |Y|N/A|
```

---

To perform a more specific replacement to may apply the substitution: `sub(/[_#!]$/, "", $20)`

Comment: That works perfectly, could you please explain me the purpose of 1 at the end.

Comment: It's a very common Awk shortcut to print every line. This is literally my first google hit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove always the last character in 20th field then following may help you on same.

```
awk -F"|" '{$20=substr($20,1,length($20)-1)} 1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){19}[^_#!]*)[#!_](|.*)/\1\3/' infile
```